# how to wrap textarea

Tags: html, textarea

how to wrap the text in textarea so that word will not be overflown to rightside and written in new line.

Comment: why do you write everything in one long sentence and without any examples so we can only imagine what you think and of course do not use any separators because if you do that sentences look normal

Answer (score 4):

Set the `wrap` attribute to `"hard"` like this:

```
<textarea 
    cols="10" 
    rows="4" 
    wrap="hard"></textarea>
```

Comment: the browser automatically inserts line breaks(CR+LF) so that each line has no more that the width of the controls, the `cols` attribute must be specified.

Answer (score 0):

According to a [www.htmlref.com](http://www.htmlref.com/Reference/AppA/tag_textarea.htm), the textarea wrap attribute is not fully standardized, but wrap="off | physical | virtual" is supported by IE and wrap="hard | off | soft" is supported by Netscape 4 (whatever that means for modern browsers).